# srt file is growing upto 16GB in temp directory in Linux - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

There is a program in production to export audit data from audit tables. The performance of the program is very poor as it is running 4 hrs just to export 5GB data. Before giving the output data there was a out of disk space where the short/temp file was actually growing upto 16GB(too huge). Once a client connecting client-server succeeded then client session runs a query which requires a results-list srt temp-file on the server-side. So the problem here is am sure this srt file generation must have taken 3 to 3:30 hrs for the completion.

Now the question is Will this srt file data is unique for the same query?
If yes then can we do something to use this srt file directly to generate the data? so that we can avoid srt file generating each time which will save us some time. I know its a stupid question but Just want to if its possible or not

Comment: downvoted because it's yet another question related to the same problem. It would be better to post a question about the query you're trying to execute along with the schema information (.df) of the table

Comment: @carlverbiest I have so many doubts and questions for the same topic and all of them cant be asked at a time. Thats why I created individual question.. Please revert the vote

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to use an SRT file from a previous session in another session.

Comment: what stops this to use in another session. Is there are a way to modify the session id in srt file if it is.

Comment: What "stops" it is that there is no way to do it. The SRT file is created by the OpenEdge runtime at startup and the runtime then manages it. You have no control over any of that and there is no mechanism at all which would permit you to say "use this other SRT file please". The option simply does not exist.